# EXTJS AJAX call need to make synchronous

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, synchronous, extjs6

I have search functionality, on every search, it hit to the server and gets data to display on the UI.
Within few seconds multiple ajax calls may happen.

Right now all the ajax calls are asynchronous due to asynchronous mechanisms all the calls are triggered at a time and whichever response receives at the end its data is displayed on the UI(reset other responses are overwritten on the store).
But I am in search to display the last ajax call response data.
I am trying to make synchronous call using new Ext.data.Store but nothing worked.

[image]
In the above image advanceTaskSearch.do has been called twice but the second call was of 596ms but the first call was of 3.03sec as the second call response was quicker than the first, first calls response is getting overwritten by second calls response.
I am assuming by making synchronous the calls will happen one after the other the latest call response data will hold by store.

snippet as bellow

```
            tasksStoreHome = new Ext.data.Store({
                model: Ext.define('tasksReaderHome' + Ext.id(), {
                extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
                fields: fieldsString
            }),
            asynchronousLoad : false,
                sorters : ['dueDate'],
                groupDir : 'ASC',
                groupField : 'TaskStatus',
                pageSize : 20,

                proxy : {
                    type : 'ajax',
                    actionMethods : {
                        read : 'POST'
                    },
                    extraParams : {
                        isDeductionTask : false,
                        query : Ext.util.JSON.encode({})
                    },
                    start : 0,
                    limit : 20,
                    url : SearchUrl,
                    async : false, // tried adding async as false here
                    
                    reader : {
                        type : 'safejson',
                        rootProperty : 'rows',
                        totalProperty : 'results',
                        keepRawData :true ,
                        async : false // tried adding async as false here
                    }
                },
                autoLoad : true
            });

       tasksStoreHome.on({
            beforesort:{fn:function(store, sorters, eOpts ){
                var column=sorters[0].getProperty();
                var direction=sorters[0].getDirection();
                var lastParams=store.proxy.extraParams;
                if(lastParams == undefined || lastParams == null || lastParams==''){
                    lastParams={};
                }
                lastParams.sort=column;
                lastParams.dir=direction;
                store.setAsynchronousLoad(false); // tried adding async as false here
                store.proxy.setExtraParams(lastParams); 
            }
           }
          });
```

I tried adding async: false at multiple places but nothing helped.
Please advise how can I achieve it.
I am using extjs6

Advance thanks.

Comment: model: Ext.define('tasksReaderHome' + Ext.id(), { <-- Something new. What do you mean on this line?

Comment: "I have search functionality, on every search, it hit to the server and gets data to display on the UI." What kind of search functionality you have? Is it a text field with 'onChange' event, which triggers the store load request? Why does your store make so many ajax requests to server?

Comment: Ext.define('tasksReaderHome' + Ext.id() --> This will generate a random ID for model.

Comment: It does two ajax calls, one is default and one is adding a few query parameters.

Comment: Ok, let's forget about "random ID for model". The QUESTION: why do you make two requests to server without params and with some params? Do you have stateful backend/server/service?

Comment: Initially, the grid will load without any conditions(primary data). If the customer has search criteria that will be loaded after the primary load. But here primary data is receiving lately than the search criteria.

Comment: So, instead of  fixing "here primary data is receiving lately than the search criteria." you are trying to make store load synchronously?

Comment: It is an expected behaver, based on a set of criteria the SQL query will run and it will fetch the data.

Comment: It is not expected behavior. The store could be autoload: false, then you could check if there are some search criteria and after that load the store. Or, if the search criteria is set by user as textfield/combobox.. fields, it would be besser to use buffered events mechanisms.

Comment: By the way, I have not found async property in the 'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax', have you overrided this class?